# Input into tuple that goes into list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to convert input from the user into a tuple that goes into a list.  I'm using the split method, but it seems to take the input and creates a tuple inside the list, but also creates another itself in the list also...I hope that made sense...anyways, I ran it in the visualizer, and saw that it was going to both each with an index of 0 and 1, so I figured I have one small detail outta whack.

In short:
Enter an employee's name. (Last, First)
and that last name, first name gets converted into the tuple and sent to the 
list.

I figured a list of employees with two values would be better as a tuple in a list, correct?  Let me know if I'm just off and it's better as a plain list.
Anyways, here's the code:

```
empList = []
empName = input("Please enter employee name. (Last name, First name):\n")
nameSplit = tuple(empName.split(","))
empList += nameSplit
salary = float(input("Please enter salary for " +str(empList[0:]) + ":\n" ))
grossSalary = salary

if (grossSalary > 100000):
    fedTax = (grossSalary * .2)
else:
    fedTax = (grossSalary * .15)

stateTax = (grossSalary * .05)
netSalary = (grossSalary - (fedTax + stateTax))

print('''\nGross Salary: {0:>5.2f} \n 
Federal Tax: {minus:>2}{1:>6.2f} \n 
State Tax: {minus:>4}{2:>4.2f} \n 
Net Salary: {3:>10.2f}'''.format(grossSalary, fedTax, stateTax, netSalary,
minus = "-"))
```

Comment: Please give an example with input, desired output, and current output.

Comment: What is the final data structure you are expecting? Your code is currently running properly, but I'm not sure what it is you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: input = (Payne, Max)

Comment: @ChrisAvina That does not help. I ran your code, and it is working. Please provide what your expected final output is for your application and explain why it does not meet your requirements.

Comment: @idjaw
input = (Payne, Max) which returns string "Payne, Max"
I want "Payne, Max to be split, converted into tuple, and then send that tuple of ("Payne", "Max") to be sent to to the list.  

The code does work properly, but when I run it in the visualizer, it shows the tuple as index 0, 1, and also shows ("Payne", "Max") as index 0, 1, respectively, in my list.  This seems to me that it is creating my tuple in my list, but also creating a copy of the same ("Payne", "Max") as two other separate items in my list  I suppose it's more of a technical clarity thing.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @ChrisAvina You don't have a list declared in your code at all, so I don't see where you are trying to insert your tuple in to your list. Also, if you do `print(type(nameSplit))` after you create your tuple, you will see it is in fact a tuple.

Comment: @idjaw 
So the empList = [] and the empList += nameSplit is not declaring my list and adding to it then?

Comment: @ChrisAvina Look at the answers posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
empList = []
empName = input("Please enter employee name. (Last name, First name):\n")
nameSplit = tuple(empName.split(","))
empList += nameSplit
```

The last line `empList += nameSplit` adds/concatentates each item from the tuple to the list. It does not add the tuple itself:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l += (4, 5)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You should use `list.append()` instead:

```
empList.append(nameSplit)
```

Now it will append the tuple:

```
>>> empList = []
>>> empName = 'Lastname, Firstname'
>>> nameSplit = tuple(empName.split(","))
>>> empList.append(nameSplit)
>>> empList
[('Lastname', ' Firstname')]

>>> empName = 'Else, Someone'
>>> nameSplit = tuple(empName.split(","))
>>> empList.append(nameSplit)
>>> empList
[('Lastname', ' Firstname'), ('Else', ' Someone')]
```

One other thing. Whitespace is left in the strings that you split with `,`. You should strip each string prior to adding it to the list, and you don't really need the intermediate variable:

```
empList.append(tuple(s.strip() for s in empName.split(",")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example session with your actual code (python3)

```
Please enter employee name. (Last name, First name):
Payne,Max
Please enter salary for ['Payne', 'Max']:
100000

Gross Salary: 100000.00 

Federal Tax:  -15000.00 

State Tax:    -5000.00 

Net Salary:   80000.00
```

Therefore, the only modification I would do is

```
salary = float(input("Please enter salary for " + empList[1] + " " + empList[0] + ":\n" ))
```

Unless from your comment `input = (Payne, Max)`, are you expecting the user to enter the parentheses?  This will **not** produce a tuple in a list.  Anyway, in your program `empList` can be a tuple or a list, it doesn't matter.